# How to easily get the required IAM permission for gcloud CLI or Firebase CLI commands

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam

I'm setting up Google Cloud Service Accounts for my CI/CD pipeline. Often times, I see that just the editor role is assigned to the service account. However, I would like to minimize the assigned permissions to follow best practices.

For me, it's hard and time-consuming to find out, which permissions are required when running commands, like

- `firebase deploy --only functions`
- `firebase deploy --only firestore`
- `firebase deploy --only hosting`
- `gcloud run deploy`

You think that roles like "Cloud Functions Developer" are enough to deploy a cloud function but this is not case because it misses the permission for Cloud Build, Secret Manager, etc.

Is there an easy way to find it out, or is there a list with required permissions? My current approach is trial and error, but it's super annoying.